# What violations does using a covariant type in a contravariant position here enable?

Tags: c#, covariance

Consider an interface with a covariant type `T`. I'm examining the case where  properties in all derived classes of this interface that use `T` are readonly, and covariant if a generic class. Suppose this interface then defines a method that uses `T` as an argument type. What violations does it permit?

For example, consider:

```
interface ICov<out T> {
  void maybe_safe_set(T v);
}
class ImplCov<T> : ICov<T> {
  public readonly T a;
  public readonly IEnumerable<T> b;
  public readonly IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> c;
  // public readonly IList<T> d; // but not this

  public void maybe_safe_set(T v) {
    // do things that can't modify state: the type of our 
    // readonly, covariant IEnumerable members can't be modified
  }
}
```

In C#, I get the error:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'ConsoleApplication.ICov.maybe_safe_set(T)'. 'T' is covariant.

which is not surprising, since `T` is found in a contravariant position. However, I can't think of a violation that can occur here.

Comment: Covariance means that the type is only consumed from the interface, never passed to it.  Think of it this way, the `out` keyword means that the type should only come out of the interface, but you have it going in as an argument of the `maybe_safe_set` method.  `T` cound instead be defined as contra-variant.  The interface is a contract and it doesn't know what a given implementation might do.

Comment: `public static class C<T> { public static T Value }` and `public void maybe_safe_set(T v) { C<T>.Value = v }` and `((ICov<object>)new ImplCov<string>()).maybe_safe_set(new object())`. Now you trying to assign `object` to `C<string>.Value` of type `string`.

Comment: If that was allowed you could cast a `ImpleConv<string>` to `ICov<object>` and then you could call `maybe_safe_set` and pass is something that isn't a `string` and then you'd have a runtime type error.  So really it doesn't have anything do to with the implementation details of the implementing class.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Doesn't simply trying it answer your question? Comments here have explained why passing a value of `T` _into_ the `maybe_safe_set()` method is illegal for `out T` type parameter. And the whole point of co-/contra-variance is that the compiler will emit an error when you are misusing the generic type. So, if you got an error, you're misusing it. If by "throws up its hands" you mean "generated a compiler error", you should say so, provide the exact text of the error, and explain what it is you don't understand about the error.

Comment: @juharr That's a very good point. Without static classes, I also couldn't think of an implementation that could act on the specific type, but PetSerAl's comment is a perfect example as well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but while I knew this is a misuse by form -- using a covariant type as a function argument -- I was wondering if this specific situation was a special case where illegal behaviour couldn't arise. I hope the edits are more clear.

Comment: It would be impractical to require the compiler to do the kind of analysis it would have to do to ensure that all the code in the method did not involve mutating the state of the implementation, never mind that the covariance is a restriction on the _interface_ declaration. It doesn't matter what the implementation does, if the interface declaration is illegal the compiler won't let you do it.

Comment: Do note that because implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` can be cast back to the actual object type, the analysis that would be required just to prove that the `IEnumerable<T>` members aren't modified is even more complex (i.e. the fact that they are `IEnumerable<T>` does not in fact prove in and of itself that the `v` value couldn't be used to modify the collection). But in any case, again: the covariance requirement is about the _interface_, not the implementation; that an implementation _could_ be safe isn't good enough. _All_ possible implementations must be safe to comply with the rules.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Oh, I wasn't aware that "`IEnumerable<T>` can be cast back to the actual object type", and its members could be modified, and am a bit confused about it. [I've posted a separate question to move that discussion out of the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506448/how-can-members-of-ienumerablet-be-modified)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree that for an arbitrary implementation, it is too much work for the compiler. Just to be clear of what I'm asking though, should my original line of thinking have been true, the compiler would only have to check that properties of derived classes were readonly and that the type parameterized covariant type arguments.

Comment: It's not a bad question. I couldn't think of a violation that could occur either, although I'm sure the compiler is right. I have to actually work through it to understand what violation it's preventing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You:

```
interface ICov<out T>    // BAD!
{
  void maybe_safe_set(T v);
}
```

Here comes the problem. As usual we have:

```
class Animal { /* ... */ }
class Dog : Animal { public void Woof() { }  /* ... */ }
class Cat : Animal { /* ... */ }
```

Then consider:

```
class Impl : ICov<Dog>
{
  public void maybe_safe_set(Dog v)
  {
    v.Woof(); // our 'Dog' v can really bark
  }
}
```

which will compile just fine.

Then this:

```
var impl1 = new Impl();
ICov<Dog> impl2 = impl1;    // OK, implements that
ICov<Animal> impl3 = impl2; // OK, you claim interface is covariant ('out')! 

var badAnimal = new Cat();
impl3.maybe_safe_set(badAnimal);  // ICov<Animal> takes in Animal, right?

// oh my God, you mad a 'Cat' bark!
```

It is always the same example when people ask about co- and contravariance.

Comment: I thought I had a good example. But you can't beat making cat bark. That one is filed away for future plagiarism forever.

Comment: _"It is always the same example when people ask about co- and contravariance"_ -- yes, it always is. Which implies the question: why answer the question _again_, rather than marking it as a duplicate of one of those questions that has the same example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about everyone else, but I find this stuff confusing too. In order to make sense of it, I need to create an example to see what violations the compiler is preventing.

Let's look at it first without the method in the interface. This is all valid:

```
interface ICov<out T> {}

public class BaseClass { }
public class InheritedClass: BaseClass { } 

ICov<BaseClass> x = new MyCov<InheritedClass>();
```

Because `T` is covariant, a variable of type `ICov<BaseClass>` can refer to an instance of `MyCov<T>` where `T` derives from `BaseClass`.

Now what if we could add a method that operates on type `T` to the interface (what the compiler is preventing?)

```
interface ICov<out T>
{
    List<T> ListOfT { get; set; }
    // ^^^ compiler doesn't like this.
}

public class BaseClass { }
public class InheritedClass: BaseClass { } 

public class MyCov<T> : ICov<T> {
    public List<T> ListOfT { get; set; } = new List<T>();
}
```

Now we can see exactly the problem this would create:

```
var usesInheritedClass = new MyCov<InheritedClass>();

//This is legal, because the type parameter in ICov is covariant
ICov<BaseClass> usesBaseClass = usesInheritedClass;

//Here's where it goes bad.
usesBaseClass.ListOfT.Add(new BaseClass());
```

`usesInheritedClass` contains a list of `InheritedClass`. But because I can cast it as `ICov<BaseClass>`, now I can add a `BaseClass` to a list of `InheritedClass`, which can't work.

So although the compiler error is confusing, it's in the right place. It doesn't try to sort out and fix my downstream errors. It prevents those downstream errors altogether by preventing a scenario in which those types can get confused.

Comment: Actually, I brought `readonly` and `IEnumerable` into this question to avoid this exact violation! I thought state was the problem, so I tried to make it as immutable as possible, but the typed methods, as Jeppe points out, remain problematic.