# How can members of IEnumerable<T> be modified?

Tags: c#, collections, covariance

In an [earlier question about generic variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486546/what-violations-does-using-a-covariant-type-in-a-contravariant-position-here-ena#comment64387107_38486546), I was informed that members of `IEnumerable<T>` can be modified. How can that be done and, seeing as variance violations arise when a covariant type can be modified, how then can `IEnumerable<T>` be covariant on `T`?

Comment: I think there is some confusion on what you mean by "members" and "modified." Can you provide an example?

Comment: @ScottHannen I thought it proper site etiquette to cut the comment discussion short in the original question and make a new question instead of clarifying, hoping that there would be a prevailing and non-trivial interpretation. i.e. I asked this in part because I don't know what the original commenter is referring to.

Comment: Oh actually, I notice now he says "implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`" which hints strongly at _some subclass_ not covariant on `T`, like a `List<T>`, whose type could be **modified** outside of the class. That makes a lot more sense for the original question, but I'm still not totally sure that's right.

Comment: @concat Creating a new question, rather than discussing it in comments is fine, but you still need to provide enough information *in this question* for it to be answered.

Comment: The context made me question: modify the members of `IEnumerable<T>`? You can't. It's a framework interface. By "members" does OP mean items in the collection, or properties of items in the collection? Likewise, by "modify" - is that referring to setting properties items or altering the references referred to by the `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 6):

You have to distinguish modifying the sequence from modifying the elements of it.

You can modify elements without any problems, since you can't modify the type of the object by using properties and functions on it.

And thus, this is all fine, since all elements in `IEnumerable<T>` are either `T` or type derived from `T`.

Such violations you mention could only happen if you could could have, for example, an object of type `Base` inside `IEnumerable<Derived>`

Comment: Though this is *entirely* correct, having read the comment linked in the question I'm not sure this is what's being asked.